# scanner doesn't work in IDEA when running in wsl

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java.util.scanner, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I was testing this simple code in IDEA running in WSL2.

```java
public class ScannerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String test = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

but got error **Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found**
and

```
Execution failed for task ':ScannerTest.main()'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

**I found the issue is idea just execute `String test = scanner.nextLine();` without letting me input.** When I ran it, it won't wait on my input and gave me error immediately.
Any thoughts are appreciated!

---

After further test, I found

1. I build a fat jar and it worked fine in wsl.
2. And it also works fine in IDEA under windows.
   So I think the problem is purely the combination of idea and wsl.

Comment: Can you show us the input you use?  Are you saying this simply prints an error immediately?

Comment: It doesn't give me a chance to input but immediatly give me error.

Comment: I'm going to *guess* that standard input (`System.in`) is being closed immediately, that there's nothing to read.  Check this in the code.  If `System.in` has an `isOpen()` method, call it and print the result.  Try to read one byte from the **raw** stream (without a Scanner) and make sure you can, verify that you do not get an EOF back.  If you can read, try to read several bytes from the raw stream and print out their values.  This might give you a clue as to what `Scanner` is complaining about.